# How to find element by id in Angualar's jqLite element object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

*I'm using this:*

```
$vehicleTypeDropdown = element.find(".vehicleTypeDropdown");
```

Then at later point of time I want to locate the `#pselect` ID element.
My `$vehicleTypeDropdown` looks like this which is the *jqLite object*:-

```
<select class="vehicleTypeDropdown" id="vehicleType">
<option id="#pselect" value="">Please Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="types in selectedType" value="Vt3" class="ng-scope ng-binding">vt3</option>
<option ng-repeat="types in selectedType" value="Vt4" class="ng-scope ng-binding">vt4</option>
</select>
```

There are two questions -

1. It's written in the *jqLite* documentation that `.find()` method only looks for the tags, not for classes or ids. So how do I get

   `$vehicleTypeDropdown = element.find(".vehicleTypeDropdown");`

   as an `jqLite` object with the content?
2. And how can I find the option with `#pselect`? I want to remove that manually, keeping in mind that it can be in any order in the options.

Comment: Couldn't  you just assign them each to a var? `var $ps = $('#pselect');` and `var $vtd = $('.vehicleTypeDropdown');`

Comment: can you a bit explain _why_ you need this? usually when use angularjs not needed manually DOM operation

Comment: @zer00ne, jqLite, not same as jQuery

Comment: @Grundy then it's very lite on the jq, it should be called jqNot

Comment: @zer00ne, yes, and your code in comment not work if jQuery not include

Comment: @Grundy That goes without saying, my assumptions based on my ignorance of jqLite.

Comment: @Grundy i just want to locate that and remove it dynamically so that user not able to see the option in select. i have that element but $('.vehicleTypeDropdown').find('#pselect') is not working, even though i have the option in $('.vehicletypeDropdown') .

Comment: **element.find(".vehicleTypeDropdown");** or **element.find("#vehicleTypeDropdown")** 
works as documentation says it shud'nt be

Comment: @navtejsingh, if this _work_, so you include jQuery to your page. also can you provide working sample, for example on plunkr?

Comment: _i just want to locate that and remove it dynamically_ you can just use `ngIf` directive for this

Comment: Consider using  the `ng-options` directive. In many cases, `ngRepeat` can be used on `<option>` elements instead of `ngOptions` to achieve a similar result. However, `ngOptions` provides some benefits such as reducing memory and increasing speed by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance. --- [AngularJS ng-options API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Answer (score 5):

Use id without `#` like `id="pselect"`

```
<select class="vehicleTypeDropdown" id="vehicleType">
    <option id="pselect" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="types in selectedType" value="Vt3" class="ng-scope ng-binding">vt3</option>
    <option ng-repeat="types in selectedType" value="Vt4" class="ng-scope ng-binding">vt4</option>
</select>
```

catch element like this

```
var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#pselect'))
elem.remove()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vorant/4sbux96k/1/

Comment: @Grundy [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/5535245) recommends avoiding the use of `#` in id attributes. It works but is not recommended.

Comment: @georgeawg, yep, i not say that this best, i just mention that with `getElementById` this work :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How to find element by id in Angular's jqLite element object

`Id` should be unique on page, so you can just find it with [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), or [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then wrap it in jqLite element.

```
var pselect = angular.element(document.getElementById('pselect'));
```

this works for:

```
<option id="pselect" value="">
```

but if you have in html:

```
<option id="#pselect" value="">
```

you should use:

```
var pselect = angular.element(document.getElementById('#pselect'));
```

---

> i just want to locate that and remove it dynamically so that user not able to see the option in select.

in this case you can simple use `ng-if` directive:

```
<select class="vehicleTypeDropdown" id="vehicleType">
    <option id="pselect" ng-if="condition" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="types in selectedType" value="Vt3" class="ng-scope ng-binding">vt3</option>
    <option ng-repeat="types in selectedType" value="Vt4" class="ng-scope ng-binding">vt4</option>
</select>
```

if condition true, element added in *DOM*, if not - not

---

if this code works:

```
$vehicleTypeDropdown = element.find(".vehicleTypeDropdown");
```

and you get right object, then on your page also included full jQuery, because as you can see in jqLite source, [*find* function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L1003) is simple

```
find: function(element, selector) {
    if (element.getElementsByTagName) {
        return element.getElementsByTagName(selector);
    } else {
        return [];
    }
},
```